# Add images on class on document load Event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created an Image slider. on document load event I am adding all left images in t1 class to give them some alignment. Similarly I am adding right side images in t2 to bend it in some other angle.

But the problem is when images are loaded they all face in same direction. Only after the Click of any image they are getting aligned perfectly.

this is the Fiddle :: 
http://jsfiddle.net/simmi_simmi123/Pukjw/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myImageFlow img').slice(1,5).addClass('t1');

        $('#myImageFlow img').slice(-3).addClass('t2');

        $("div img:first-child").removeClass('t2');

            alert("first freeeeeeee");

            $("img").click(function(){

           console.log('i am Image Flip');

               var t = $(this);
               this.className = '';

               t.prevAll().removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
               t.nextAll().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
            });
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to show the corresponding CSS that aligns/rotates the images to have any idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: we need a jsfiddle working example to be able to help fully

Comment: jsfiddle added i cant add whole code but please see u will get ides

Answer (score 0):

You are only applying the rotation when an image is clicked. To solve this, select the first image and apply the rotation to all the others.

```
$("#myImageFlow img:first").nextAll().removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
```

your updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Pukjw/4/

Ive also added some hover functionality, and updated the css to make it easier to see all the images...